# ServletContainer handle requests

Tags: tomcat, jersey

we have jersey ServletContainer and we want that servlet will handle requests for a grace time when shutting down the tomcat.
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could register your implementation of [ContainerLifecycleListener](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.25.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/ContainerLifecycleListener.html)
and `onShutdown` method will be called before application is reloaded.

Comment: thanks.do you have an example how can i make my  ContainerLifecycleListener to be called when shutting down?